# Creating a screensaver for windows and mac - Silverlight?

Tags: windows, silverlight, macos, screensaver

I am not sure even of a starting point with this.. however knowing that Silverlight works across win/mac platforms (as far as I know!), is it possible to create a silverlight based screensaver?

If not, are there any tools (no flash skills unfortunately!)

Any starter points would be cool..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By now Silvelight is being deprecated, but if you need to run web pages as a screensaver, my startup is creating a product to do exactly that, it's called [Screensaver Ninja](https://Screensaver.Ninja) and you can find more about it at https://screensaver.ninja. That means that all you have to do is develop the web app and leave the screensaver part to us.

Here's a screenshot of how you configure it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is only usable as a web browser plugin on Mac OS X. It cannot be practically used to build screensavers.

Additionally, there's good reason to believe that Silverlight is being abandoned by Microsoft. I'd avoid it for any new development.

Comment: Hey thanks @duskwuff .. yes just trying to get a handle on this.. however I think you are correct that silverlight will "morph" into something else/HTML5 based I guess.. 

I have written a few silverlight apps/out of browser apps because I wanted a rich environment for both mac/win.. apart from Adobe Air, not sure if there any other contenders?